# Obtener información de una pagina web Usando el componente chromium delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi

estoy con un problemita que no consigo resolver de ninguna manera, estoy usando un componente para delphi 10.3 CEF4Delphi, este componente facilita usar paginas modernas en Chromium, estoy intentando pasar un valor de una pagina a una variable string, ya conseguí mostrarlo en una ventana emergente del navegador, pero mi inconveniente ahora es obtener el valor de esa ventana emergente,
también e echo que en el input y el botón de búsqueda haga un click automáticamente, solo el inconveniente es obtener el valor de la ventana emergente.
Con el componente TWebbrowse es mas simple de copiar información de la pagina cargada, solo que paginas modernas no acepta cargar algunos datos.
Espero la respuesta con gusto.

```
    procedure TForm1.GoBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    var JScode:string;
    begin
    JSCode := 'var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];' +
    'var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");' +
    'for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {' +
    ' var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");' +
    ' for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {' +
    '   alert(cells[j].innerHTML);' +
     ' }' +
     '}' ;
    Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(JSCode, 'about:blank', 0);
  end;
```

Comment: Hay varios métodos nombrados en los foros del componente: consola, devtools, extensiones Javascript (añades una función Delphi al Javascript).
Yo personalmente he usado el método de la extensión, echa un vistazo a las demos de la carpeta Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

En el javascript que ejecutas, podrías escribir el contenido a la consola y utilizar el evento `OnConsoleMessage` para *capturar* el contenido dentro de tu programa Delphi:

En lugar de

```js
alert(cells[j].innerHTML);
```

Escribir en la consola con el método log:

```js
console.log(cells[j].innerHTML);
```

Y en el formulario, escribir un manejador para el evento `OnConsoleMessage`:

```
procedure Tform1.webvConsoleMessage(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser; const message,
  source: ustring; line: Integer; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(message);
  Result := True;
end;
```

Incluso, puedes utilizar un *marcador* para diferenciar los mensajes que puedan llegar a la consola por otras fuentes, por ejemplo, declarar una constante:

```js
console.log('XxX' + cells[j].innerHTML);
```

Y luego *filtrar* los mensajes que no sean de tu origen:

```
PREAMBULO_CONSOLA        = 'XxX';

procedure Tform1.webvConsoleMessage(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser; const message,
  source: ustring; line: Integer; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  if     (length(Message) > 0)
     and (Copy(Message, 1, 3) = PREAMBULO_CONSOLA)
  then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(copy(message, 4, MaxInt));
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

OJO: No estoy totalmente seguro que este evento se lance dentro del hilo principal, ya que chromium ejecuta una serie de hilos *por su cuenta*. Si el evento no se lanza en el hilo principal, no puedes acceder elementos de la VCL, como he hecho yo en el ejemplo `Memo1.Lines...`. Ya te tocará a ti ver que el código que escribas sea thread-safe en ese caso.

Comment: La respuesta de jachguate es correcta pero quisiera añadir otro método más. También puedes registrar extensiones de JavaScript. Este método es menos fácil de usar que los mensajes de consola pero es mucho más versatil. Puedes leer mi respuesta aquí : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303829/how-to-invoke-the-delphi-function-from-javascript-using-cef4delphi/64304191#64304191

Comment: @Salvador, siéntete libre de replicar tu excelente respuesta aquí, en español, no solo es válido, sino que es deseable tener el contenido directamente en castellano. Un saludo.